# What is the pythonic way of writing a long if-else statement?

Tags: python

I am quite new to Python though I have had experience in Java before.

I have the following code to convert a score into an interval delta (as part of a Spaced Repetition System (SRS) program I am implementing). This code looks ugly and not very readable. Typically I would have used a switch statement in Java. But in python I could not find an equivalent. Hence I have written this code which produces the result. But I want to take this opportunity to learn different options for achieving the same output using more pythonic ways. I would appreciate any help, even if they are pointers to resources that I can read to improve this code.

```
   # Convert score into an interval delta
    if score == 0:  # Perfect page
        intervalDelta = +3
    elif score == 1:  # 1 Word Mistake
        intervalDelta = +2
    elif score <= 3:  # 3 Word Mistakes
        intervalDelta = +1
    elif score == 4:  # 1 Line Mistake
        intervalDelta = 0
    elif score <= 8:  # 2 Line Mistakes
        intervalDelta = -1
    elif score <= 12:  # 3 Line Mistakes
        intervalDelta = -2
    elif score <= 20:  # 5 Line Mistakes
        intervalDelta = -3
    elif score <= 30:  # 7.5 Line Mistakes - Half a page
        intervalDelta = -5
    else:  # More than half a page
        intervalDelta = -7
```

Comment: I mean, this code is pretty readable to me. my only suggestion would be to use python naming conventions, so `interval_delta` instead of `intervalDelta`. This seems fine to me, there's nothing "wrong" about it.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga thank you very much for making me realize that I am not using python naming convention. I realized that I have carried forward the conventions from my earlier work with Java. Will rectify it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't find the long `if` statement *that* unreadable, although I'd change to using `<=` for consistency (since the `==` cases are already single possibilities using `<=`). If I were implementing it from scratch, I'd probably write something like the following simply to have the associations more visible:

```
from math import inf


SCORE_DELTAS = (
    (0, +3),
    (1, +2),
    (3, +1),
    (4, +0),
    (8, -1),
    (12, -2),
    (20, -3),
    (30, -5),
    (inf, -7),
)


def score_to_delta(score):
    for bound, delta in SCORE_DELTAS:
        if score <= bound:
            return delta
```

Comment: wow - what a different way of implementing the long if-else logic. I am so grateful to see this way of thinking.

Answer (score 1):

The official [position on switch statements](https://docs.python.org/2/faq/design.html#why-isn-t-there-a-switch-or-case-statement-in-python) is that switch statements are easily done with if statements, so writing long if statements is the Python way. [PEP 275](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0275/) and [PEP3103](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3103/) document the reasons why switch statements were omitted. In practice though there are several  [alternatives to the switch statement.](https://www.pydanny.com/why-doesnt-python-have-switch-case.html). The most common is the dictionary approach to switches.

```py
def case_a():
  print('Executing case A')

def case_b():
  print('Executing case B')

def case_else()
  print('Executing default case')

def dict_switch(argument):
    switch = {
        'a': case_a
        'b': case_b
    }
    return switch.get(argument, case_else)()

dict_switch(x)
```

Another approach is to keep all of the conditional logic in a class, but I find this is only necessary when there is a significant amount of conditional logic.

```py
class Switcher:
    def numbers_to_methods_to_strings(self, argument):
        """Dispatch method"""
        # prefix the method_name with 'number_' because method names
        # cannot begin with an integer.
        method_name = 'number_' + str(argument)
        # Get the method from 'self'. Default to a lambda.
        method = getattr(self, method_name, lambda: "nothing")
        # Call the method as we return it
        return method()

    def number_0(self):
        return "zero"

    def number_1(self):
        return "one"

    def number_2(self):
        return "two"
```

In your case, however, I think @asthasr approach is the cleanest.

Comment: I would upvote if this answer summarized the relevant information instead of just relying on the links...

Comment: @infosmith, thank you so much for the 2 alternatives to switch. My aim in asking this question is to learn more about python and I am glad to learn about the dictionary way of implementing switch, and about the getattr() function. However, I am not sure how I can translate the idea to my case where the condition tested is not equality - can you please give me some pointers?